# CSS force text to fit into a particular height by overflowing its parent horizontally

Tags: css, overflow

I've got a relatively long phrase that consumes way too much space on mobile devices. It looks something like this:

```css
.artificial-phone-viewport {
  width: 320px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.text {
  /* 
   * Don't want to change font-size, because text
   * sometimes maybe shorter and 2.2rem is perfect
   * for phrases that are not as long
   */
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}
```

```html
<body class="artificial-phone-viewport">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus saepe illum a magni sequi error fugit dolore neque voluptates in laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What I want is to make this text span at most, let's say, `10rem` height. If it can't fit into `10rem` of height, it should instead expand horizontally, maybe, overflowing its parent, maybe like this:

```css
.artificial-phone-viewport {
  width: 320px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}
.text {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<body class="artificial-phone-viewport">
  <!-- Deleted container to reduce code, it actually
       doesn't matter, because it anyway spans
       100% width and height of its parent -->
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur<br/>
    adipisicing elit. Temporibus saepe illum<br/>
    a magni sequi error fugit dolore neque<br/>
    voluptates in laborum.
  </div>
</body>
```

P.S. This snippet is just an example of what I want to see, I don't want any of these `<br/>`s or `white-space: nowrap`. Also I want the text to overflow its parent, because I then can use Javascript to scale it propertly, but it is not very relevant for the question, I suppose.

Comment: You'll need Javascript for this.

Comment: If you want the text to overflow parent, you could try adding position: absolute to the text div, that would work. But I guess it's just a workaround. There should also be something concrete to do this.

Comment: @RahulSharma, could you show a snippet, how to do this with `position: absolute`? I planned to use it anyways, so it may fit nicely in my scenario. I mean, if I set `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 10rem` to `.text`, it doesn't really want to increase in width.
Also I don't really imagine, why it would span these `10rem`, wouldn't it just take one line? I could do it with `width: 1000%` for text, but I don't really want it. Would be nice if you could show a snippet

Comment: Maybe changing HTML would help, I have access to it. Like wrapping every word in `<span>` and using flexbox somehow, don't see how, though

Comment: Please let me know. https://shorturl.at/xCEFM

Comment: @RahulSharma, mhm, it works in this case, but firstly, it doesn't span as many lines as it can, and, most importantly, it won't work if `.artificial-phone-viewport` is replaced with real small phone viewport, where it has no space to expand

Comment: Then maybe adding  `overflow-x: scroll` would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a way to do it with Javascript, although I don't like it too much. I just increased the width of the element, until the height was small enough, like this

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.text')
const rem = parseFloat(
  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize
)

let width = text.clientWidth / rem
while(text.clientWidth > 10*rem) {
  width++
  text.style.width = `${width}rem`
}
```

```css
.artificial-phone-viewport {
  width: 320px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}
.text {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}
```

```html
<body class="artificial-phone-viewport">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus saepe illum a magni sequi error fugit dolore neque voluptates in laborum.
  </div>
</body>
```

It's not very nice, but it works for me. If someone finds a way to do it without javascript, I'm open to other solutions